# SFC CIM module fail to load system->Config after re-deployment

Tags: enterprise-1.13, third-party-module, core-config-data

I have a client who we moved from one host to the next host. The migration went fine except for the SFCSaved and SFCCore modules. I can not load system->config with the modules turned on. All I get is a white screen. I do not get any errors. I have removed all core_config_data items as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: I didn't realize I knew Garth, I just emailed him and I will report back on this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFC modules require IonCube loader... That solved my problem